# What do other R users do when initialising the environment within knitr code chunks?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm writing my first knitr document (in markdown), and I'm finding that I have to repeat a lot of things at the start of each chunk, like:

````
```{r case1,fig.width=10,fig.height=8,echo=FALSE}            # 01 
root <- "O:/"                                                # 02 
code <- paste(root,"Rcode/zpsys.functions.R",sep="")         # 03 
source(code, echo=FALSE)                                     # 04 
andir <- "Visit.2015-10-05/Performance/analysis/"            # 05 
savepath <- paste(root,andir,"tr99a.rdata",sep="")           # 06 
load(savepath)                                               # 07 
with(tr99a,{                                                 # 08 
    plot(stamp,msg,pch=1,cex=0.5,xlab="Time",ylab="Msg/sec") # 09 
    lines(stamp,lowess(msg,f=0.3)$y,col="blue")              # 10 
    lines(stamp,lowess(msg,f=0.1)$y,col="red")               # 11 
})                                                           # 12 
```
````

Lines #8 to #12 are the "important" stuff.

Lines #2 to #7 are "merely administrative", to allow me to change computers, datasets, and versions of my functions. As a programmer, all that repetition offends me -- I know I'm going to need at least *one* line of initialisation code, but are there good ways to do this in less than six?

---

OK, I had a close vote as "opinion-based", so here's the altered question:

Would experienced R Programmers please contribute their code for doing similar things? Hmph.

Comment: why do you repeat lines 2-7 for every chunk? Also, `source`ing code kinda defeats the reproducibility of `knitr`. packages > `source`. in fact that is how I would solve your issue. make your code & data into a package and `library` that puppy.

Comment: @hrbrmstr 
 
Oh. Doh. I thought each code chunk was in it's own environment, but if that were true, on reflection, it would be very inconvenient. Thanks. As to making a package, I have to confess that I'm not "doing literate" -- this is just an iterative process to build a one-off presentation, so reusability and documentation are way down the (today's) list of priorities. If you'd care to add an answer pointing out my fallacy about the environment needing to be set up every time, I'll accept it. Many thanks.